# How to avoid deleting .0 on floats with NumberFormatInfo

Tags: c#

I've done some research and can't find it.

I'm using float values and .ToString() with NumberFormatInfo  to build some GLSL source code with it.

But NFI turns a 1.0 to "1" instead of "1.0" what leads to an integer in GLSL code and makes the graphiccard cry about implicit integer convertation.

I can't use ToString() without NFI because it takes the country's standard decimal separtor. So in Germany this leads to 1.5 => "1,5"

How do I get NFI to avoid deleting trailing zeros?

Comment: Some code would be good, as in waht argument are you passing to ToString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should to the trick:

```
 .ToString("0.0###############")
```

If you want less decimals, remove the `#` (I have put enough decimals for the `double` precision of 16 digits)

or, if you need to specify the culture,

```
 .ToString("0.0###############", yourCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. But looks a bit hacked :D

Answer (score 1):

You can set `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits` to a number of zeroes you want to display. Then, you can display your number with this code:

```
var nfi = new CultureInfo("en-us").NumberFormat;
nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
//outputs 1.00
1.ToString("N", nfi);
```

Comment: Sorry changes nothing.

Comment: Works now, but adds unnecessary zeros. I will stick with the solution above, but thanks for your work :)

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
ToString("0.0");
```

Comment: But it returns `1.0` for `1.043` too, so I don't think it's ok.